# Converting HTML pages with MathML equations to Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, html, file-conversion, pandoc, mathjax

My goal is to convert this document (https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/lorentztrans.html) which contains math into word document with well formatted equations.

Why only Microsoft Word you ask? I am teaching myself physics from this lecture notes. I make all my notes in onenote (on my Ipad with handwritten equations and hand-drawn diagrams using ipencil). The thing is, OneNote has same equation system as the Microsoft Word. If its converted into Word, then it is converted into OneNote.

I have tried all possibilities I could by Googling. I tried the following methods without success.

Method 1: Copy pasting MathML into MS Word. It is working for some simple equations, I found elsewhere. But strangely, it isn't working for any equations from this website. I think there is something strange about MathML of this website.

Method 2: Converting from HTML to docx using pandoc. I saved the html (only) of this page. Then used `pandoc -s input.html -o output.docx`. It skipped all the equations.

Method 3: Copypasting directly into MS Word and Apache OpenOffice Write.

I don't mind converting first into intermediate format and then converting it into Word.

NOTE: I am looking for an automatic solution because I need to do it for hundreds of pages. The author has written his lecture notes on various  in this format.

Comment: Have you tried `pandoc -s input.html --mathml -o output.docx`?

Or `pandoc -f html --mathml -o output.docx input.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math tags in the document look like this:

```html
<math xmlns='//www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML' style='background-color:#'>
 <semantics>
  <mi>v</mi>
 </semantics>
</math>
```

The XML namespace is given as a protocol-independent URI, i.e., it starts with `//`. This is not correct, it must use the `http:` protocol, like so: `http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML`.

Pandoc gets confused by this as well, since it isn't valid MathML, and so doesn't recognize it as an equation. It works well if one adds the `http:` prefix. The solution is therefore to do a search-and-replace in the input HTML document, fixing the xmlns attribute, and then pass the fixed result to pandoc.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I totally missed that. I added 'http:' and executed `pandoc -s input.html --mathml -o output.docx`. It worked brilliantly. Thanks a lot once again :)